# How to use google-spreadsheet in nodejs

Tags: node.js, discord.js, google-sheets-api

I want to use the google-spreadsheet API to fetch and write data to a sheet in my Discord bot (using discord.js). For some reason, I can't get it to work. This is my code:

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet')
const creds = require('../service-account.json')

module.exports = {
    /...
    execute(message, args) {
        accessSpreadsheet()
    }
}

async function accessSpreadsheet() {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('<id was here>')
    doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds)
        .then(() => {
            doc.getInfo()
                .then(info => {
                    console.log(`Loaded doc: ` + info.title + ` by ` + info.author.email)
                    const sheet = info.worksheets[0]
                    console.log(
                        `sheet 1: ` + sheet.title + ` ` + sheet.rowCount + `x` + sheet.colCount
                    )
                })
        })
}
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
 (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Google API error - [404] Requested entity was not found.
     at createError (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
     at settle (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
     at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
 (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
 (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: This appears to be something wrong with the ID you are trying to use

Comment: @Cloud how could I know that? I used the long ID in the sheet URL...

Comment: I have not used this particular API before, but reading the error message, that's the first thing I would look into. That or perhaps an authentication issue due to the spreadsheet being private and thus Google acting like it doesn't exist to outside users.

Comment: Can I ask you about the version of `google-spreadsheet` you are using?

Comment: The sheet is indeed private, but it has been shared with the service account. (it's Editor now) 
@Tanaike I'm using version 3.0.11

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could know that you use `google-spreadsheet@3.0.11`. From this, I think that your script can be used for v3.0.11 while `info` becomes `undefined`. But from the error message of `Requested entity was not found`, I would like to propose to confirm the Spreadsheet ID again. Because this error message occurs when no Spreadsheet ID used. If the Spreadsheet ID is correct, please confirm whether the Spreadsheet is shared with the email of the service account again. When the Spreadsheet is not shared with the service account, such error occurs. So pleas be also careful this.

Comment: @Tanaike So apparently the ID changed for some reason (maybe because the sheet was shared with another person?) and I changed it back in my code. Now it says this:
`(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`. Probably what you said about the `info` stuff. How could I fetch the title then?

Comment: Ok so I actually used async/await and it works now! Thank you for your help 

Comment: @Quinten Althues Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I should actually use async/await for achieving this. My code has become:

```
async function accessSpreadsheet(message, args, msg) {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('<id was here>')
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds)

    await doc.loadInfo()
    console.log(doc.title) //whatever you want to log goes here
})
```